# maintaining a constant total of excel cells

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a column with 3 cells: A1, A2 and A3. I want the numerical total of the 3 cells to remain constant as I increase or decrease any one of the 3 cells. That is to say, I need any increase or decrease of any cell to be evenly distributed between the other 2 cells. For example, I start with 3 + 5 + 2 = 10. I change 5 to 6 so then I have 2.5 + 6 + 1.5 = 10 automatically. Please bear in mind that in fact I will have about 20 cells that I want to equal a constant 100. thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Fill **A1** through **A20** with values that add up to *100*:

[image]

Then place the following *Event Macro* in the worksheet code area:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rng As Range, Delta As Double
    Set rng = Range("A1:A20")
    If Intersect(Target, rng) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    Delta = (100 - Range("A21").Value) / 19
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        For Each r In rng
            If r.Address <> Target.Address Then
                r.Value = r.Value + Delta
            End If
        Next r
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Once the macro is installed and active, it will detect any change to the values in **A1** through **A20** and adjust the other values to preserve the 100.  Change only one cell at a time.

Because it is worksheet code, it is very easy to install and automatic to use:

1. right-click the tab name near the bottom of the Excel window
2. select View Code - this brings up a VBE window
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you have any concerns, first try it on a trial worksheet.

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the macro:

1. bring up the VBE windows as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

To learn more about Event Macros (worksheet code), see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/event.htm

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**